# Running a form with a picturebox being constantly updated in a background worker is unresponsive to mouse events

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, backgroundworker

Firstly, thank you all for all your help over the years.  I have found many solutions on this site but this one appears to be unique.

What I have is a form with a picture box that is being created in a background worker (as I need the UI to be responsive during the display if the background worker).  This picture box is being updated with a while loop running within the background worker.

The background worker is called:

```
private void Play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFile.ShowDialog();

    FileName = openFile.FileName;

    this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        VisualPlayer.Player player = new VisualPlayer.Player(FileName);
}
```

and this is a sample of the the function being called in the backgroundWorker

```
public void VideoPlayer(string fileName)
{

    PlayerScreen.VideoWindow videoWindow = new PlayerScreen.VideoWindow();
    videoWindow.Show();
    videoWindow.TopMost = true;
    PictureBox pictureBox = (PictureBox)videoWindow.Controls[0];

    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    var millisecondsRemaining = GetFileLength(fileName);
    var endTime = startTime.AddMilliseconds(millisecondsRemaining);

    while (millisecondsRemaining > 0)
    {
        millisecondsRemaining = Convert.ToInt32(endTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);
        ... do the pictureBox updates here ...
    }

}
```

So everything is working and all is good but for one thing, I am not able to select the videoWindow.  I need to be able to select it, move it, double click it to resize it, etc, but when I move the mouse over it, all I have is the hourglass.

Now my solution is to add the dreaded Application.DoEvents() within the While Loop to capture the mouse events, but everywhere and everyone here recommends I not use it.

So I was wondering, is there another way to handle the mouse events on the otherwise unresponsive background worker form?

Comment: Are you using a picture box as a video player?

Comment: Sort of.  I have a file (fileName) that contains a stream of bitmap information that I am parsing (... do the pictureBox updates here ...) and I am displaying this bitmap in the picture box.

Comment: Can you use .Net 4.5?

Comment: I have the trial of 2012 installed, and use it at work... Why?  Is there a solution there?

Comment: Try something with tasks and synchronization contexts.  If you are using .Net 4.5, then you could code it with async/await.

Comment: Tried Task.  I ended up losing the ability to interact with the UI as well as not being able to interact with the videoWindow.  I also tried running it in a New Thread rather than a BackGroundWorker and get the same result.  The UI was still responsive, but was still unable to interact with the videoWindow.  Do you know of any async/await samples that may be relevant?

Comment: How you implement it isn't such a big deal.  If you do work on the main thread, it's got to be quick so the message pump can process OS events.  That's what will lock up the UI.  If it's not quick, you can execute it from a background thread as long as you invoke the work to update the UI onto the main thread.  That's all I've got.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  You tried, and that is pretty much all I've got too.

Comment: This looks like you're updating the `PictureBox` in order to show some kind of "video" or "animation". Why don't just put a Video in there instead?

Comment: Because it is not a video.  Unfortunately the file I am working with does not contain video information.  What I have is a file that contains BitMap information.  As time progresses, I find the time I am at, and render the new BitMap from the file (...Do the pictureBox updates here...) and display it to the PictureBox in the VideoWindow.